# Controlling external device by tapping into existing transistor

Tags: bjt, fet

I'm working on one project where I cannot figure out on how I can control my external device by tapping into some home appliance. Just to note, that I have very limited knowledge of electronics and I learn by practice.

Here is the circuit of my control device (sorry for quality, I took it from the official service manual).

[image: circuit]

I need to turn on/off my external device when Q4 is open or closed. Q4 is controlled through 5V coming from the microcontroller. My external device is controlled via 24V.

My idea was to connect the ground of my device to the control device and then use the input to base of Q4 to drive the MOSFET on to switch my device. However, I cannot understand how should I connect the MOSFET.

How can I switch my load with Q4 properly?

My external load is: 24V 3A.
MOSFETS that I have are IRLB8721.
Q4 is DTC143Z - NPN 100mA 50V Digital Transistor (Bias Resistor Built-in Transistor).

Comment: What mosfet? What is the load current? Why not a bjt like the circuit?

Comment: Why not just use the COFFEE_PUMP signal (at the input side of Q4's base resistor, rather than the transistor side) directly - then this question simplifies to "how do I switch a load [please describe the load] from a 5V control signal" and this is an easily Googleable task. MOSFET is good since it won't draw extra current from the MCU and risk overloading its output driver.

Comment: Q4 looks like the resistors are inbuilt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tapping into Q4's on/off state in the same way they do it here; with an opto-isolator.

You see the pair R40+LED? That's exactly what you should do, by connecting your own resistor and LED, where the LED is part of your own opto-isolator IC.

In that way, you have absolutely no concerns about accidental ground loops or interfering power supply rails, because your circuit will be completely isolated from the coffee maker's electronics.

I assume you're powering your own circuitry from an independent 24V supply, so this is how I envisage all this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgTE2L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are responsible for everything in the blue box, and the two grey wires to the coffee machine.

When the LED in the coffee machines's own opto-isolator is lit, so is the LED in yours. That switches on the transistor inside, pulling the P-channel MOSFET Q1's gate low, and switching it on too.

Please note that I've used two different ground symbols. The one on the left is inside the coffee machine, the one in the blue box is yours. This is important, they are not connected together in any way by you. It's possible that both may be connected together via the wall plugs to mains Earth, that's OK, but *do not* connect them together explicitly yourself.

**Edit**: I included R3, to divide the collector voltage by two. Otherwise the maximum allowed \$V_{GS}\$ of the MOSFET could be exceeded.

**Edit2**: I included D1, only necessary if you are switching on and off a nasty device like a motor or relay. There's no harm leaving it there, regardless of the load.